# How to exclude an item when using @foreach in Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade, laravel-5.3

How to exclude an item when using @foreach (blade) in Laravel?

example:
a user has some articles, in article detail page:

```
<p>Article detail：</p>
<h2>{{$article->title}}</h2>
<p>{{$article->content}}</p>

<h4>The other articles of this user：</h4>
@foreach ($articles as $article)
<p>{{$article->title}}</p>
@endforeach
```

**Question:**
In `@foreach`, how to exclude the article that has been shown above?

Comment: Artisans do process data in controller or even in model, view is only for displaying data.

Answer (score 5):

There are a few ways to do this.
One option would be a simple if check in the template:

```
<p>Article detail：</p>
<h2>{{$article->title}}</h2>
<p>{{$article->content}}</p>

<h4>The other articles of this user：</h4>
@foreach ($articles as $otherArticle)
    @if($article->id !== $otherArticle->id)
        <p>{{$article->title}}</p>
    @endif
@endforeach
```

Another, perhaps better option would be to exclude the main article from the data in the controller:

```
function showArticle(Article $article)
{
    $otherArticles =  $article->user->articles->filter(
        function($otherArticle)  use($article) {
            return $otherArticle->id !== $article->id;
        });
    return view('someview')
        ->with('article', $article)
        ->with('otherArticles', $otherArticles);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you dont want to show the `article` at detail page in `The other articles of this user：`

At controller you should send `id of article` on this detail page to view

And at view

```
<p>Article detail：</p>
<h2>{{$article->title}}</h2>
<p>{{$article->content}}</p>

<h4>The other articles of this user：</h4>
@foreach ($articles as $article)
    @if($article->id !== $article_id)
        <p>{{$article->title}}</p>
    @endif
@endforeach
```

with `article_id` is `variable` you send from `controller`

Answer (score 0):

Use a for loop starting from the second element.

```
<p>Article detail：</p>
<h2>{{$article->title}}</h2>
<p>{{$article->content}}</p>

@if (count($articles) > 1)
<h4>The other articles of this user：</h4>
@for ($i = 1; $i < count($articles); $i++)
<p>{{$articles[$i]->title}}</p>
@endfor
@endif
```